# Классификация данных по нескольким условиям. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, классификация, кластеризация, folium

Всем привет!
Просьба помочь/ направить в какую сторону думать со следующей задачей: У меня есть исходные данные с геокординатами заказов и суммой заказов, их обычно более 20 тыс строк. Я пытаюсь распределить эти заказы между "Пунктами выдачи" по нескольким условиям.

*df с исходными данными:*

[image: Датафрейм исходной таблицы]

**Условие 1** - Адреса заказов должны относиться к ближайшему "Пункту выдачи". Тут были рассмотрены различные алгоритмы классификации, но остановился на простом варианте - расчет наименьшего расстояния между адресом заказа и "Пунктом выдачи". **Думаю эта задача выполнена)**, в итоге получил распределение заказов:
[image: Распределение заказов между "Пунктами выдачи"]

В df с расстояниями я нахожу ближайший "Пункт выдачи" и добавляю в сходный df.

*df с расчетом расстояний по каждому заказу:*

[image: Расчет расстояний]

*и вывожу это на карту:*

[image: Координаты заказов на карте]

**Условие 2** - У нас есть 5 пунктов выдачи, и нам нужно что бы количество заказов распределилось по определенном условиям:

- "Пункт выдачи А"  - должен получить 30% заказов.
- "Пункт выдачи Г"  - должен получить 25% заказов.
- и т.д. распределение 100% заказов по 5 "Пунктам выдачи"

И вот тут я сломался(( тут вроде что то с сортировкой делать надо, но как пройти матрицу с подсчетом количества для каждого "Пункта выдачи" непонятно, можно предположить что надо выбрать "Пункт выдачи" с наименьшим кол-вом заказов и вначале для него найти точки заказов, а оставшиеся точки заказов добавить к оставшимся заказов и снова пройтись уже для следующего "Пункта выдачи". Но тут может произойти такой момент, что доставки которые были бы ближе к пункту выдачи Н, оказались в пункте выдачи Р, лишь потому, что он был по очереди прохода первее.

**Условие 3** -если вообще это возможно) по аналогии с "Условием 2", при распределении заказов, учитывать и "Сумму заказов", например, что б для пункта выдачи А было не больше 15% заказов и не больше 400 тыс.

Буду очень благодарен за за любую помощь!
Спасибо!

Comment: Я бы попробовал считать "меру уверенности попадания в кластер" и при распределении заказов распределял необходимое количество отсортировав от наиболее уверенных к менее уверенным. Тогда в пункт попадут первым делом заказы, которые точно ему должны принадлежать. А "неуверенные" заказы попадут если в другой пункт, то и не страшно.

Comment: Согласен с @CrazyElf. Разбиваете город на кластеры. Для каждого кластера создаете пул пунктов выдачи, раскидываете равномерно до уровня критического наполнения (по приоритету деньги потом наполненность или наоборот), при достижении которого пункт ставится на паузу. По мере опустошения ниже какого-то уровня снова пункт включается в работу.

Comment: Хмм.. интересно, надо что то погуглить) а так идеи вроде понятны. Конечно разбивать город на кластеры не подойдет, у меня уже есть определенные центроиды и как раз эти кластеры и хочу создать автоматически. Протестирую пока с уровнем критического наполнения для работы с "условием 2" - распределение количество заказов, а потом к суммам заказов подойду. 
Спасибо!
Результат выложу)